# Scan only the first 12 digits of a 13 digit barcode using a Symbol LS9208i

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a Symbol LS9208i barcode scanner that I accidentally used to scan the `SET DEFAULTS` barcode in the manual. Products like "Nutella" have a barcode of 9300698000018, which is 13 digits long, but the issue I'm having right now is trying to find a way to only scan the first 12 digits. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to include a lot more information in this post for people to help you, such as the model of barcode scanner that you're using.

Comment: sorry for that...i edited my post..the model is symbol LS9208i

Comment: Unless I'm counting it incorrectly, the example barcode that you used (930069800001) only has 12 digits, but you say that it has 13. Are you missing a digit in there?

Comment: yeah, haha... typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last digit is a check digit. Try to enter the first 12 digits to http://www.upcdatabase.com/checkdigit.asp and you'll see that the last one can be calculated from the first 12.

If [this manual](http://www.dx.no/download/ls9208.pdf) I googled, is correct for your device, you can change the settings of your bar code scanner by scanning appropriate barcodes from the manual. You probably want to change the "Transmit UPC-A/UPC-E/UPC-E1 Check Digit" settings, see page 160 on the PDF.

Try scanning the barcode labeled "Do not Transmit UPC-A Check Digit". That should configure your scanner to transmit only the first 12 digits when scanning UPC-A barcodes.

Comment: i don't get the process...can you atleast some instructions step by step

Comment: any help? can you give a step by step...

Comment: i follow your instruction but it gives me 13 digits..

Comment: I've been doing your instruction, I've tried to scanned the "Do not Transmit UPC-A Check Digit" but when I tried to scan our product it scan 13 digits. any help please